# CSS: Increase div width, incrementally, with size of browser window

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a div that I want to scale in intervals with the size of the browser. I can do this easily with js or jQuery, but I think there is a CSS only solution. Maybe media-query is one solution, but maybe there is a simpler one?

As the window size increases by 100px, I want to add another 100px to the width of my div. I only want to increase the div's width in 100px increments, so using % does not seem like an option.

Comment: Media queries is your ticket. Why the reservation?

Comment: I thought it would be, just wasn't sure if that was meant for something more specific :)

Answer (score 1):

```
@media all and (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 200px) {
  div {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 300px) {
  div {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
```

and so on...

Comment: So doing it this way, I'll have to write probably 15 or so cases. Is there a more programmatic way to do this?